# Extended Lasso problem ( two L1 norms)

Tags: regression, optimization, lasso, convex

I am trying to find a closed form solution for the following problem :
$$
\underset{\beta}{\operatorname{minimize}} \frac{1}{2} || y - X \beta ||^{2} + \lambda || \beta ||_{1} + \mu || \beta - \gamma ||_{1} 
$$

I know that for the problem : $$ \underset{\beta}{\operatorname{minimize}} \frac{1}{2} || y - X \beta ||^{2} + \lambda || \beta ||_{1} $$
The solution would be : $$ \text{sign}(\hat{\beta})(| \hat{\beta} | - \lambda)^{+} $$
but when adding the term : $$ \mu || \beta - \gamma ||_{1}  $$ I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: What are $\mu$ and $\gamma$ in this context? Just constants like lambda?

Comment: $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are the regularization parameters and $\gamma$ is a constant